# Using JQuery, how can I check to see if a dropdown menu contains a value?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Using JQuery, how can I check to see if a dropdown menu contains a value? By value, I don't mean the text displayed as a menu item. I mean the ID (val) of the item. I have a list of items already in the dropdown menu, and I want to add more. Before I do that, I want to make sure I do not duplicate any key-value pairs.

Comment: By `ID` do you mean the value?  Or do you actually mean the html `id` attribute?

Comment: The value of the dropdown menu item

Comment: Did you try `if($('option[value="value_id_here"]').length){ //exists }`?

Comment: You want to do this when the page is loaded or when something is clicked?

Comment: @Shef Thanks. It worked. Does this check every dropdown on the page? I need to check a specific one.

Comment: @j08691 When something is clicked

Comment: @Mark13426 [You can easily limit it to a specific selector](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/JgHLh/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do what you want. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web5me/2pf4Y/))

html

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="foo">foo</option>
</select>
<button data-add="foo">add foo</button>
<button data-add="bar">add bar</button>
```

js

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var new_val = $(this).data('add');

    if ($('option[value='+new_val+']', '#sel').length) {
        alert('nope, exists!')
    } else {
        $('<option value="'+ new_val +'">'+new_val+'</option>').appendTo( $('#sel') );
    }
});
```

If you use an older jQuery version than 1.7 use `.bind` instead of `.on`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  if ($("#drpentry").find("option[value='Dog']:contains('Ds')").length > 0) {

             alert('exist entry');
       }
       else {

           alert('not exist');
       }

   });
```

check here : http://jsfiddle.net/Eemqh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shortened version of Marc Diethelms solution, without the need of data-attributes: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pf4Y/2/)

```
$('button').bind('click', function() {
    var new_val = $(this).html().split(' ').splice(1).join(' '),
        $sel = '#sel';
    $('option[value='+new_val+']', $sel).length > 0 ?
        alert('nope, exists!') :
        $('<option value="'+ new_val +'">'+new_val+'</option>').appendTo($sel);
});
```

Comment: Nice footwork Simon, however the data attrs are simply there to make the example work in absence of the actual data source the OP might have to use. Your example breaks as soon as you're having to implement more than one language. Generally on should not rely on the presentational value of an input as the logical value.

And in any case you can be pretty sure there won't be ANY buttons on the page that will add new option elements in any real life scenario. I put them there just for sake of providing an example.